# IAP, Braintree, Tribe: Looking for the right tool

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, stripe-payments, braintree

I'm developing an application and I'm looking which tool should I use for adding priced features in it.

Before answering, there are some things to take in account, that's what blocking me:
     1 - We have a web application which already manage purchases for the web, and we would prefer going through our API to manage purchases as it's already here.
     2 - We have 2 differents type for purchasable items : a subscription (for now we have 3 months or 12 months subscription, but we're working on making only one kind of subscription) and a virtual currency in a virtual wallet that the user can fill as he wants.
     3 - Last but not the less, when a user subscribes or add currencies to his virtual wallet, those items are also available on the web application.

I've troubles choosing IAP or Braintree/Tribe, because it's seems to me that some Apple's guidelines are contradicting each others in my situation :

```
 "11.1
      Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
 11.2
      Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected"
```

Those first rules are saying that I just cannot use any third-party API to add priced content in my application.

```
 "11.3
 Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the App will be rejected"
 In my case, I feel like the subscription and our virtual currency are concidered "goods and services" used outside of the app, because the user can use it on our web application

 "11.4
 Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must consume those credits within the App"
 Here, Apple seems to tell you "Ok, go for the virtual currency, BUT we prevent you from using it outside of your iOS application"
```

So what should we do ? Can we add our purchases inside of our application, or are we forced to say to the user for buying them on our web application ? And if we can add them in our application, does it go to the In-App purchase or to the "third party payment API" because it's used on our web app too ?

Thank you in advance for your help
Bilkix

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but my understanding is that you have to use Apple's In-App Purchase to unlock content within your own app (for instance, if your app is a game and you want to sell additional content such as new levels, you should use IAP).

For selling goods that aren't relevant to the app (i.e. the app is merely a storefront), then you must use an external processor.

For reference, here is the support article from Stripe that covers this topic: https://support.stripe.com/questions/apple-and-stripe-tos-and-fees

(Disclaimer: I work for Stripe.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem comes with the virtual currency. Here is exactly what we want to do :

In our service, users can buy virtual currency (let's call it Gold for convenience) and use it to have an online course with another user. At this point, the Golds are transfered to the "teacher" who could change it to real money if he wants to.

We saw that Candy Crush enabled buying Gold on the iOS app and it's usable on their web app. But it feels like violating the Apple's guidelines, and that's the point we're trying to figure out

Comment: My own intuition would be that you need to use an external processor, not IAP, for this scenario, but I couldn't tell you for sure. You can try writing to Stripe's support: https://support.stripe.com/email. They'll probably be able to give you a more definitive answer.

Comment: Hope so, I'll try. Thank you !